# Why are my textures blurry?

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image]

This is an image of a 50 samples render of my scene. I know, low samples but no matter what samples I render it at the textures are always blurred.

[image]

This is my camera options.

[image]

And this is my render options. How do I un-blur these textures?

Comment: How did you set up your materials? Are you rendering at 100% resolution? What nodes are you using in the compositor? please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: Probably you used Glare node set to Fog Glow option in the composite node setup. Include a screenshot of the composite node tree used for that render

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/how-to-render-a-model-with-pixel-art-sprite-textures-and-have-it-not-be-blurry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like Minecraft, in which case the textures are **intentionally** low resolution. You're looking at *interpolation*, which is normally good, but not for this. To turn it off, go to your image texture node and change **Linear** (the texture interpolation) to **Closest**.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.