# Images Look Blurry in Blender No matter how high the render samples are or that the settings in sampling is final

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: Blurry looking render]

When I render with the camera in blender, no matter how high the render samples are or that the sampling is final rendering it still looks blurry.(unless it's the grass)

Comment: Please search for answers first before asking a question as it is quite likely that it has been asked before and has an answer.
Check the answer provided to a similar question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47968/5693

Comment: 200 samples for rendering is a low number of samples. There is no such thing as "Sampling is final"

Answer (score 1):

There can be at least three causes of blurriness like you are experiencing.

1. Image interpolation method
2. DOF (depth of field)
3. anti-aliasing

Looking at your render I'm pretty sure you have the camera set so you are focused on the background, and the foreground is blurred. Thus your issue is DOF.

#### DOF

To remove all DOF simply select the active camera, now in the properties window head to the *Camera* tab, scroll down to the *Depth of Field* section and set the *Size* of the aperture to **0**.
[image: camera DOF settings]

---

#### Image interpolation

If the DOF did not fix it, then I'd move on to changing the image interpolation on your textures.
You are going to have to go through each material and every texture node, and set the [interpolation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html#properties) to *Closest*.
[image: Image texture node showing the interpolation setting]

---

#### Anti-aliasing

Don't think this is your issue but might as well add it here for completeness.

To turn off anti-aliasing in cycles go to the *Film* section of the *Render* tab in the *Properties* panel, and set the *Width* of the *Pixel Filter* all the way down (0.01).

[image: anti-aliasing setting]

Answer (score 0):

if the mesh is unwrapped, try scaling the UVs in the image editor. Also enable the node wrangler add-on then go to the node editor and click on your image texture node and press ctrl+t, then play with the scale values in the mapping node. Hope you have success.